# Comparing int and String from LinkedList

Tags: java, string, linked-list, compare, int

I've got a problem.

I'm trying to compare a String and a int but can't seem to get working. 
What am I doing wrong?

Getting this from Eclipse:

> The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List

```
    int numberOfMoves;
    List<String> highscoreLinkedList = new LinkedList<String>();

    if (moves < Integer.parseInt(highscoreLinkedList[2])){
      highscoreLinkedList[2] = Integer.toString(moves);
      highscoreLinkedList[1] = name;
    }
```

This is for a highscore textfile for a game I'm making. The String at index 2 is a number of moves and the int moves is also a number of moves.

Comment: Well, what is it *telling* you you're doing wrong?

Comment: Oops, forgot about that. Edited now.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access a list element using `highscoreLinkedList[2]` - that syntax is reserved for arrays. To access a list you have to use the `get()` method, i.e. `highscoreLinkedList.get(2)`

Comment: Oh my god, I'm so stupid. Totaly mixed Array and LinkedList up... stupid stupid stupid! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to treat list as an array, but the only way to access elements of the is through calling [get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) method. Your code does not compile.

Comment: Oh my god, I'm so stupid. Totaly mixed Array and LinkedList up... stupid stupid stupid! Thanks!

Comment: By the way, random-accessing LinkedList's elements is not efficient. Consider using ArrayList or array.

Answer (score 1):

`List`s don't work the same way as arrays in Java. To access a certain element, you have to use the `get()` method, and to get the element, you need to use `set()`, like so:

```
// you have highscoreLinkedList[2], it should be:
highscoreLinkedList.get(2);

// you have highscoreLinkedList[2] = ..., it should be:
highscoreLinkedList.set(2, Integer.toString(moves));
```

You can see all of the methods for `LinkedList` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

Comment: Oh my god, I'm so stupid. Totaly mixed Array and LinkedList up... stupid stupid stupid! Thanks!